Calculate duration between 2 milestones based on criteria
Given the following problem: An ice truck is rented for a certain duration with a start date "x" and an end date "y".
Example:
rental start date in cell b1 = 27/05/2025
rental end date in cell b2 = 14/07/2027
However, the ice truck is anticipated to only sell ice cream in the sunny months, from April to September.
This criterium is defined in cell f1=4 and cell f2=9.
What I am searching for is a formula that returns me the total "vending days" in the range explained above, so the sum of all days "s" matching these criteria, without failing when spanning multiple years. The output shall be stored in cell b5.
It would be appreciated if a formula could be provided (ideally non-array) for this and not a VBA automation. I would also want to avoid having to use a "helper sheet" with the dates from 27th May 2025 till 14th July 2027.


Try using the following formula:


• Formula used in cell B4
=LET(
     _Seq, SEQUENCE(B2-B1+1,,B1),
     ROWS(FILTER(_Seq, (1-ISNA(XMATCH(MONTH(_Seq),SEQUENCE(F2-F1+1,,F1)))))))


Or, Using TOCOL():
=LET(
     _Seq, SEQUENCE(B2-B1+1,,B1),
     ROWS(TOCOL(_Seq/(1-ISNA(XMATCH(MONTH(_Seq),SEQUENCE(F2-F1+1,,F1)))),2)))


Explanations:

Using LET() function to define variables and reduce redundant calculations.
Using SEQUENCE() function creating a series of dates which starts from B1 and ends on B2
Same way creating a series using SEQUENCE() for the month range.
Using XMATCH() function to match the exact months needed and extracting only those matches using 1-ISNA( which is equivalent in using ISNUMBER()
Finally, using either TOCOL() or FILTER() extracting the dates which are need to get the final vending days counts.


Updated in one single line method:
=SUM(1-ISNA(XMATCH(MONTH(SEQUENCE(B2-B1+1,,B1)),SEQUENCE(F2-F1+1,,F1))))



thanks again, after playing around with this I found a formula that works too, and is a bit shorter: =SUM(--ISNUMBER(XMATCH(MONTH(SEQUENCE(B2-B1+1,,B1)),SEQUENCE(F2-F1+1,,F1),0)))

@DorianIL yes it is the same thing, i just used the LET() to make it readable and understand the steps! Here it is : =SUM(1-ISNA(XMATCH(MONTH(SEQUENCE(B2-B1+1,,B1)),SEQUENCE(F2-F1+1,,F1))))
